# Generating beanplots in a forloop with LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, sweave

I am trying to automatically generate a number of beanplots with a forloop, and outputting them into a LaTeX document. Starting with a data frame (that successfully generates beanplots), I am using the code below. The intent is to output consecutive beanplots into the document. I am able to do this by writing a beanplot command for each desired plot (it works fine), but obviously this would be much nicer if I could do it with a forloop. However, when I try to use a forloop, instead of outputting say 9 plots, it only outputs the last plot. Any ideas on why this is? I tried using fig.keep='all' and plot.new(), neither helped. Compiling with Sweave. Thanks!

```
<<beanplots,fig.keep='all'>>=
#fig.keep='all' <- this did not help
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(beanplot))
for (i in length(unique(Data[['Days']]))){
   # plot.new()   ##  this did not help either
  beanplot(Readings~FactorLevels,
         data=subset(x=Data, subset=(Data[['Days']]==i)),
         main=paste("Day",i,sep=" "),
         cex.axis=0.7)
}
@
```

Comment: This is [R FAQ 7.22](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f)

Comment: Side comment: `for (i in length(...))` will always execute once only. Recommend `for (i in `:length(...))` or better yet `for (i in seq_along(...))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`beanplot` works with the Lattice graphics library. As such, it does not automatically produce plots when running non-interactively. You must explicitly call `print()` on the object returned by the call to produce a plot. Try

```
<<beanplots,fig.keep='all'>>=
#fig.keep='all' <- this did not help
suppressPackageStartupMessages(require(beanplot))
for (i in unique(Data[['Days']])){
   # plot.new()   ##  this did not help either
  print(beanplot(Readings~FactorLevels,
         data=subset(x=Data, subset=(Data[['Days']]==i)),
         main=paste("Day",i,sep=" "),
         cex.axis=0.7))
}
@
```

Comment: Correct for Sweave and in general. When using knitr instead of Sweave, print is not required

Comment: I had tried using print() but that did not work either.

Comment: See @r2evans comment on your original question. I've updated my code with his suggestion. You looping structure was also wrong. YOu didn't need `length()`.